# Finding subsets that can be completed to tuples without duplicates

Tags: algorithm, math, set, puzzle

We have a collection of sets A_1,..,A_n. The goal is to find new sets for each of the old sets.

```
newA_i = {a_i in A_i such that there exist (a_1,..,a_n) in (A1,..,An) with no a_k = a_j for all k and j}
```

So in words this says that we remove all the elements from A_i that can't be used to form a tuple (a_1,..a_n) from the sets (A_1,..,A_n) such that the tuple doesn't contain duplicates.

My question is how to compute these new sets quickly. If you just implement this definition by generating all possible v's this will take exponential time. Do you know a better algorithm?

Edit: here's an example. Take

```
A_1 = {1,2,3,4}
A_2 = {2}.
```

Now the new sets look like this:

```
newA_1 = {1,3,4}
newA_2 = {2}
```

The 2 has been removed from A_1 because if you choose it the tuple will always be (2,2) which is invalid because it contains duplicates. On the other hand 1,3,4 are valid because (1,2), (3,2) and (4,2) are valid tuples.

Another example:

```
A_1 = {1,2,3}
A_2 = {1,4,5}
A_3 = {2,4,5}
A_4 = {1,2,3}
A_5 = {1,2,3}
```

Now the new sets are:

```
newA_1 = {1,2,3}
newA_2 = {4,5}
newA_3 = {4,5}
newA_4 = {1,2,3}
newA_5 = {1,2,3}
```

The 1 and 2 are removed from sets 2 and 3 because if you choose the 1 or 2 from these sets you'll only have 2 values left for sets 1, 4 and 5, so you will always have duplicates in tuples that look like `(_,1,_,_,_)` or like `(_,_,2,_,_)`.

This problem seems difficult, but it would be great if there was a polynomial time algorithm.

Another way to look at this is to picture the sets A_i on the left and the values on the right, with a line connecting a set and a value if the value is in the set.

Comment: Are you writing a kakuro/sudoku solver?  If so, do you have restraints on the possible values, such as always 1 - 9, there are always at most 9 sets, that sort of thing?

Comment: Good guess :) It's not for sukodu but it *is* for a kind of logic puzzle solver / generator (to check if there is a unique solution). There is no fixed limit on the number of sets or how many elements are in the sets, but these numbers will be small in practice (say less than 20). But still 20^20 is a big number of tuples to check!

Comment: I suppose there could be several valid solutions? If that is the case, are you looking for some optimal solution in some sense?

Comment: I don't think there are several solutions. The definition of newA_i is unambiguous? I'd like to find new sets such that *all* values that are bound to generate invalid tuples are removed. Either a value can be used in a valid tuple or it cannot.

Comment: Yeah. I believe you're right.

Comment: "remove all the elements from A_i that can't be used to form a tuple" *and keep the rest* :)  otherwise it seems that the trivial solution of empty sets fits the constraints.

Comment: This seems like something you could use dynamic programming on. I'm not very good at dynamic programming so I can't suggest an exact solution, but you should look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the assignment algorithm might help here. The basic step would be to fix on a number in one of the Ai and then see if that number can be used with others chosen from the Aj to select a number from each set without repeat. Think of the numbers as people, and the numbers in set Aj as the people who might be used to perform task j. Then the problem of finding a different representative from each Aj is the problem of assigning a different person to each task.

Wikipedia treats the assignment problem as having all assignments possible and a cost for each http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem. In our case we can use 0 and 1 as costs to mean can do and can't do and look to see if there is a zero cost answer.

Comment: Thanks! I clicked some links in wikipedia and found that there even is a specialized algorithm for 0 and 1 weights (maximal bipartite matching). Perfect.

Comment: I was thinking that this simply finds a solution if one exists, but you just modify the graph to only include the edge between A_i and x in my description below and use the algorithm to try to find a complete graph.  If you find one, you include that x in B_i and if not, you leave it out.  Awesome.  I'm totally coding this for my sudoku solver.  I wonder if I can fiure out a way to use this for a kakuro solver.  I don't know how to include the sum section though.

Comment: But first I need to understand the algorithm.

Comment: Yes, you can just try the numbers in every set one by one and check if there is a solution if you choose that number. But you can actually do it much faster by making a modification to the maximal bipartite matching algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

I'm still thinking about how to solve this, but I decided to try rewriting the question to see if it gave me any inspiration.

Given a set of N sets:

```
A_i = {a_i0, a_i1, ..., a_ij, ...}
```

find

```
B_i such that x is in B_i if and only if:
   x is in A_i and
   there exists {c_0, c_1, c_2, c_3, ..., c_N} such that
      c_i = x and
      c_k is in A_k for all k and
      c_k != c_l for all k != l
```